# Serial double regulation

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I am new to Modelica and OpenModelica and I am trying to learn by myself this language.

I am currently working on a model which the objective is to validate the principle of a serial double regulation:

I placed a heat exchanger. In the left of the heat exchanger, the two valves are installed to regulate a heat flow (87 000 W max.). In the right of the heat exchanger, the three-way diverter valve is regulated to obtain the final temperature (T_final) equal to 80 °C. The regulation is the PID regulation. The pump creates a constant mass flow rate (1 kg/s).

I impose different temperatures thanks to the component "temperature_input". The objective is to obtain a final temperature of 80 °C whatever the value of the input temperature (with 87 000 W max.).

With the model below, the valves are not regulated. Also, I would like to assure a maximum heat flow of 87 000 W (maybe with the component "FixedHeatFlow"?). And I don't know if the problem is badly defined, or if the values of the PID controllers are wrong.

Can someone help me please?

Thank you very much for your answers

Here is a schematic diagram to illustrate my problem:

[image]

The model:

```
model SousStation84

replaceable package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWaterOnePhase;
replaceable package Medium1 = AixLib.Media.Water "Medium model";
replaceable package Medium2 = AixLib.Media.Water "Medium model";

Modelica.Fluid.Sensors.MassFlowRate m_in_primary(
  redeclare package Medium = Medium)
  annotation(
      Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-150, 36}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

Modelica.Fluid.Sensors.MassFlowRate m_out_primary(
  redeclare package Medium = Medium)
  annotation(
      Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-150, -60}, extent = {{10, -10}, {-10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

AixLib.Fluid.Sensors.TemperatureTwoPort T_in_primary(
  m_flow_nominal = 1,
  redeclare package Medium = Medium)
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-104, 36}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

AixLib.Fluid.Sensors.TemperatureTwoPort T_out_primary(
  m_flow_nominal = 1,
  redeclare package Medium = Medium)
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-70, -60}, extent = {{10, -10}, {-10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

Modelica.Fluid.Sources.FixedBoundary source(
  
redeclare package Medium = Medium,nPorts = 1, p = 100000, use_p = true)
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(extent = {{-340, -70}, {-320, -50}}, rotation = 0)));

AixLib.Fluid.Sensors.TemperatureTwoPort T2(
  m_flow_nominal = 1,
  redeclare package Medium = Medium)
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-280, -60}, extent = {{10, -10}, {-10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

Modelica.Fluid.Sensors.MassFlowRate m2(
  redeclare package Medium = Medium)
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-242, -60}, extent = {{10, -10}, {-10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

Modelica.Fluid.Valves.ValveIncompressible Valve_1(
  Kv = 16,
  dp_nominal = 60000,
  m_flow_nominal = 1.8,
  redeclare package Medium = Medium)
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-198, 36}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

AixLib.Fluid.Sensors.TemperatureTwoPort T1(
  m_flow_nominal = 1,
  redeclare package Medium = Medium)
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-228, 36}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

Modelica.Fluid.Valves.ValveIncompressible Valve_2(
  Kv = 16,
  dp_nominal = 60000,
  m_flow_nominal = 1,
  redeclare package Medium = Medium)
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-192, -60}, extent = {{10, -10}, {-10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

Modelica.Blocks.Continuous.LimPID PID_1(
  Td = 0,
  Ti = 300,
  controllerType = Modelica.Blocks.Types.SimpleController.PID,
  k = 3,
  limitsAtInit = true)
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-224, 98}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Constant constant2(
  k = 353)
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-290, 98}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

Buildings.Fluid.HeatExchangers.PlateHeatExchangerEffectivenessNTU hex(
  redeclare package Medium1 = Medium1,
  redeclare package Medium2 = Medium2,
  Q_flow_nominal = 87000,
  T_a1_nominal = 353.15,
  T_a2_nominal = 333.15,
  configuration = Buildings.Fluid.Types.HeatExchangerConfiguration.CounterFlow,
  dp1_nominal = 120000,
  dp2_nominal = 100000,
  m1_flow_nominal = 8,
  m2_flow_nominal = 6,
  use_Q_flow_nominal = true)
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-25, -17}, extent = {{-25, 25}, {25, -25}}, rotation = -90)));

AixLib.Fluid.Sensors.TemperatureTwoPort T_final(
  m_flow_nominal = 1.8,
  redeclare package Medium = Medium)
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(extent = {{152, 30}, {172, 50}}, rotation = 0)));

AixLib.Fluid.Sensors.TemperatureTwoPort T_V3V(
  m_flow_nominal = 1,
  redeclare package Medium = Medium)
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {126, -36}, extent = {{-10, 10}, {10, -10}}, rotation = -90)));

Modelica.Fluid.Sources.Boundary_pT temperature_input(
  redeclare package Medium = Medium,
  T = 333,nPorts = 1,
  use_T_in = false)
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {270, -76}, extent = {{10, -10}, {-10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

AixLib.Fluid.Sensors.TemperatureTwoPort T_input(
  m_flow_nominal = 1,
  redeclare package Medium = Medium)
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {224, -76}, extent = {{10, -10}, {-10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

Modelica.Blocks.Continuous.LimPID PID_2(
  Td = 0,
  Ti = 300,
  controllerType = Modelica.Blocks.Types.SimpleController.PID,
  k = 3,
  limitsAtInit = true)
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {62, 104}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

Modelica.Fluid.Sensors.MassFlowRate m_input(
  redeclare package Medium = Medium)
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {186, -76}, extent = {{10, -10}, {-10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

Modelica.Fluid.Machines.ControlledPump pump(
  N_nominal = 1500,
  m_flow_nominal = 1,
  p_a_nominal = 110000,
  p_b_nominal = 130000,
  redeclare package Medium = Medium)
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {146, -76}, extent = {{10, -10}, {-10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

Modelica.Fluid.Sources.FixedBoundary fixedBoundary(
  nPorts = 1,
  redeclare package Medium = Medium)
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {272, 40}, extent = {{10, -10}, {-10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

AixLib.Fluid.Sensors.TemperatureTwoPort T_out_secondary(
  m_flow_nominal = 1.8,
  redeclare package Medium = Medium)
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(extent = {{20, 30}, {40, 50}}, rotation = 0)));

Modelica.Fluid.Sensors.MassFlowRate m_V3V(
  redeclare package Medium = Medium)
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {126, -4}, extent = {{10, -10}, {-10, 10}}, rotation = 90)));

AixLib.Fluid.Actuators.Valves.ThreeWayLinear threeWayLinear(
  dpValve_nominal = 60000,
  m_flow_nominal = 1.8,
  use_inputFilter = false,
  redeclare package Medium = Medium)
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {128, 40}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

Modelica.Fluid.Sensors.MassFlowRate m_out_secondary(
  redeclare package Medium = Medium)
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {88, 40}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

Modelica.Fluid.Sensors.MassFlowRate m_in_secondary(
  redeclare package Medium = Medium)
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {82, -76}, extent = {{10, -10}, {-10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Constant constant1(
  k = 353)
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-4, 108}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

Modelica.Fluid.Sensors.MassFlowRate m_final(
  redeclare package Medium = Medium)
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {210, 40}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

AixLib.Fluid.Sensors.TemperatureTwoPort T_in_secondary(
  m_flow_nominal = 1,
  redeclare package Medium = Medium)
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {30, -76}, extent = {{10, -10}, {-10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

Modelica.Fluid.Sensors.MassFlowRate m1(
  redeclare package Medium = Medium)
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-284, 36}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

Modelica.Fluid.Sources.FixedBoundary fixedBoundary1(
  redeclare package Medium = Medium,
  nPorts = 1,
  p = 200000,
  use_p = true)
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(extent = {{-348, 26}, {-328, 46}}, rotation = 0)));

Modelica.Fluid.Sensors.SpecificEnthalpyTwoPort specificEnthalpy(
  redeclare package Medium = Medium)
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-64, 36}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

Modelica.Fluid.Sensors.SpecificEnthalpyTwoPort specificEnthalpy1(
  redeclare package Medium = Medium)
  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-112, -60}, extent = {{10, -10}, {-10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

equation
  connect(m_in_primary.port_b, T_in_primary.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-140, 36}, {-114, 36}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(m2.port_a, Valve_2.port_b) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-232, -60}, {-202, -60}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(source.ports[1], T2.port_b) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-320, -60}, {-290, -60}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(T1.port_b, Valve_1.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-234, 36}, {-208, 36}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(T2.port_a, m2.port_b) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-270, -60}, {-252, -60}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Valve_1.port_b, m_in_primary.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-188, 36}, {-160, 36}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Valve_2.port_a, m_out_primary.port_b) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-182, -60}, {-160, -60}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(constant2.y, PID_1.u_s) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-279, 98}, {-236, 98}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(PID_1.y, Valve_1.opening) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-213, 98}, {-198, 98}, {-198, 44}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(PID_1.y, Valve_2.opening) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-213, 98}, {-192, 98}, {-192, -52}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(hex.port_b1, T_out_primary.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-40, -42}, {-40, -60}, {-60, -60}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(T_input.port_a, temperature_input.ports[1]) annotation(
    Line(points = {{234, -76}, {260, -76}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(threeWayLinear.port_2, T_final.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{138, 40}, {152, 40}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(m_input.port_a, T_input.port_b) annotation(
    Line(points = {{196, -76}, {214, -76}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(m_V3V.port_b, T_V3V.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{126, -14}, {126, -26}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(constant1.y, PID_2.u_s) annotation(
    Line(points = {{7, 108}, {30, 108}, {30, 104}, {50, 104}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(m_out_secondary.port_b, threeWayLinear.port_1) annotation(
    Line(points = {{98, 40}, {118, 40}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(T_final.T, PID_2.u_m) annotation(
    Line(points = {{162, 51}, {162, 80}, {62, 80}, {62, 92}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(pump.port_a, m_input.port_b) annotation(
    Line(points = {{156, -76}, {176, -76}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(T_V3V.port_b, pump.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{126, -46}, {126, -58}, {156, -58}, {156, -76}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(T_in_secondary.port_a, m_in_secondary.port_b) annotation(
    Line(points = {{40, -76}, {72, -76}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(m_final.port_b, fixedBoundary.ports[1]) annotation(
    Line(points = {{220, 40}, {262, 40}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(PID_2.y, threeWayLinear.y) annotation(
    Line(points = {{73, 104}, {128, 104}, {128, 52}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(T_out_secondary.port_b, m_out_secondary.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{40, 40}, {78, 40}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(m_in_secondary.port_a, pump.port_b) annotation(
    Line(points = {{92, -76}, {136, -76}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(m_V3V.port_a, threeWayLinear.port_3) annotation(
    Line(points = {{126, 6}, {126, 21}, {128, 21}, {128, 30}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(T_final.port_b, m_final.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{172, 40}, {200, 40}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(hex.port_a2, T_in_secondary.port_b) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-10, -42}, {-10, -42}, {-10, -76}, {20, -76}, {20, -76}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(hex.port_b2, T_out_secondary.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-10, 8}, {-10, 8}, {-10, 40}, {20, 40}, {20, 40}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(T_final.T, PID_1.u_m) annotation(
    Line(points = {{162, 52}, {65.5, 52}, {65.5, 66}, {-224, 66}, {-224, 86}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(m1.port_b, T1.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-274, 36}, {-238, 36}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(fixedBoundary1.ports[1], m1.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-328, 36}, {-294, 36}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(m_out_primary.port_a, specificEnthalpy1.port_b) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-140, -60}, {-124, -60}, {-124, -60}, {-122, -60}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(specificEnthalpy1.port_a, T_out_primary.port_b) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-102, -60}, {-80, -60}, {-80, -60}, {-80, -60}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(T_in_primary.port_b, specificEnthalpy.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-94, 36}, {-74, 36}, {-74, 36}, {-74, 36}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(specificEnthalpy.port_b, hex.port_a1) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-54, 36}, {-40, 36}, {-40, 8}, {-40, 8}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
end SousStation84;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at [ask]. Is the whole code needed to reproduce the problem or could it be cut down to speed up bug search?

Comment: Hello Hille, the whole code reproduces the problem (no need to cut down this code)

Comment: What they meant was: Can this code sample be made smaller and still show the problem? I.e., remove (irrelevant) parts until the model does not show the problem you have anymore. This way the code sample you show others that would like to help gets smaller, easier to analyse, and the probability of actually finding the bug/suggesting a solution goes up. :-)

Comment: Also, make sure that the model compiles/checks/runs first if possible. As it is, this does not pass the "Check" phase because the `Medium` you are using is not defined - `Base class Medium not found in scope...`.

Comment: Also, you say you want to regulate on the heat flow on the left side, but you are measuring the *temperature*  on the right side. You can probably add 2 SpecificEnthalpy sensors before/after to calculate the heat dumped into the HX and regulate on that.

Comment: Hello Christoph, thank you for your replies.

- To be more specific, the code sample has been already cut : the project I am working is very difficult, so my colleagues and I decided to simplify the code and to concentrate on the serial double regulation. That is why there is no need to cut down the code above.
- The medium has been defined in my package. I updated the code with the definition of the medium.
- I am going to try the SpecificEnthalpy sensors, I will inform you if anything new happens.

Comment: I just tried the 2 SpecificEnthalpy sensors and I don't know how these are able to regulate the heat flow.

Furthermore, my colleagues and I concluded it is due to the component "source_primary" that the regulation does not work: if the flow rate is imposed, the valves will never regulate.

Now I have to delete the component " source_primary" and find a way to impose the heat flow while keeping the heat exchanger. I am stuck, can someone help me please?

Comment: The 2 specific enthalpies in combination with the mass flow rate will give you the amount of heat dumped into the HX by the primary side. And you're correct - if you are imposing the mass flow rate upstream and the pressure downstream, regulating the valve resistance will only change the upstream pressure - instead, use two pressure boundaries with sufficiently different pressures to drive the flow.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Christoph. - The thing is I don't really need the enthalpy sensors because I know the amount of heat thanks to the heat exchanger (I can plot the value of its parameter "Q_flow"). - As you said, I placed two pressure boundaries to drive the flow. However, the regulation is not working. Is it because of the components "LimPID" (the values of the PID, wrong choices of the setpoint and measurement, etc…)?
I updated the code with the enthalpy sensors (I let them in the model, just in case) and the pressure boundaries.

Comment: I also add a diagram to facilitate the understanding of my problem

Comment: Well, the measurement input in PID_1 is still T_final, although you say you want to control the heat flow into/through the HX (not the temperature) with PID_1. 
Also, both PIDs are taking the same quantity T_final as their input, I don't know how well that will work (I don't think this is a typical cascaded control setup).
I recommend that you build up your model step-by-step to reduce complexity, e.g. first get the HX primary side control setup working with a simplified secondary side (e.g. a slowly rising temperature but no 3-way valve), then add components and tweak again.

Comment: I am coming back to give you the conclusion to this message I wrote several months ago. After talking with colleagues, we agreed to test the dual regulation in real life instead of simulating it. After installing our machine, we simply changed the PID values and the control is now working properly. Thank you again for your time!